# Como bajar de la versión 3.7 a 3.6 de Python?

Tags: python

Tengo la versión de Python 3.7 en Windows añadido al PATH y no quiero que me estropee nada si la cambio en mis proyectos de eclipse. El caso es que no tengo ni idea de cómo cambiar la versión sin que me afecte o lo más mínimo.
Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: No es necesario *bajar* la versión de python(ademas que no se puede) ya que puedes tener multiples versiones de python, asi que descarga el instalador de python3.6 desde el sitio oficial, instalalo y cambia el PATH si es necesario.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que te comentan es cierto. Yo no uso Python en window, pero en Ubuntu uso *virtual environment* de modo que puedo usar ambientes independientes con distintas versiones, tanto de Python como de cualquier paquete. Te recomiendo que lo uses, aunque uso Linux, me consta que está disponible en window también.

Answer (score 0):

Para trabajar con varias versiones de Python y sus librerías utliza pyenv.
Esto te permite trabajar con varios entornos virtuales, cada uno con sus ambientes y sin interacción entre ellos.

Espero te sirva!!